# location Hyperlink in eclipse console

Tags: java

I want to have the filename that we pass in the function, displayed as a hypertext in the Intellij Console using java code.
Clicking on the link will open up the file

Please let me know if anyone find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use the formatting of a stack trace.

```
System.out.println("at java.awt.Color.toString(Color.java:711)");
```

Then IntelliJ will convert it into an hyperlink to that file and open it at the specified line.